# If user rank is higher than, else

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a rank based navigation system. So the higher rank an user is, the more navigation option he gets. I did:

```
$rank = "SELECT rank FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

And then I tried:

```
if ($rank > 5) { 
// show rank 5 navigation
} else {
// show lower than rank 5 navigation
}
```

But it didn't work for me..

Any ideas?

Comment: Any debugging would have shown you why this doesn't work and research would have told you why this is wrong. I suggest you do both of these before asking a question on Stack Overflow. You should read [how to best ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "But it didn't work for me". Means?  Did you expect it to do some cooking for you?

Comment: Did you even execute the SQL or did you just define it in a string variable in the hopes that magic would happen? You'll need to feed this into a database driver like PDO to get results. Have a look at [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for insight into how to tackle this problem.

Comment: @Akhil No need to be salty

Comment: @tadman Yes I did execute the SQL

Comment: @DanBowell It doesn't look like you did since the same variable that's holding the SQL is later being compared as if it's a result set.

Answer (score 1):

The examples below should be enough to get you started on the correct path.

Look in to [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for details on the best way to go about pulling information from MySQL.

Also, take a look at MySQL's [Comparison Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) and PHP's Comparison Operators.

```
<?php

    // Place everything in a function to keep it somewhat organized.
    function displaySpecialUserMenu($username){

          // Connect to database
          $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDatabaseName', 'testDatabaseUser', 'testPassword123');

          // Turn on error mode. Turn this OFF for production.
          $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

          // Select statement should return "1" if a user's rank is above 5
          $statement = $db->prepare('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE rank > 5 AND username = :username');

          // Prepare the variables for the statement.
          $statement->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

          // Run the prepared statement
          $statement->execute();

          // Store the result (It'll be either a 0 or a 1) in $result
          $result = $statement->fetchColumn();

          if($result>0){
              // User's rank is greater than 5
              // Display menu here
              echo '[high_rank_menu_here]';
           }else{
              // User's rank is greater than 5
              // Display menu here
              echo '[low_rank_menu_here]';
           }


}

// Place this line where you want your menu to display.
displaySpecialUserMenu($_SESSION['username']);


?>
```

You can also do the logic with PHP instead of with MySQL as in the example above.

```
<?php

function displaySpecialUserMenu($username){

        // Connect to database
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDatabaseName', 'testDatabaseUser', 'testPassword123');

        // Turn on error mode. Turn this OFF for production.
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // Select rank from user
        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT rank FROM users WHERE username = :username");

        // Prepare the variables for the statement.
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        // Run the prepared statement
        $statement->execute();

        // Store the result
        $rank = $statement->fetchColumn();

        if($rank>5){
            // User's rank is greater than 5
            // Display menu here
            echo '[high_rank_menu_here]';
        }else{
              // User's rank is greater than 5
              // Display menu here
              echo '[low_rank_menu_here]';
        }
}

// Place this line where you want your menu to display.
displaySpecialUserMenu($_SESSION['username']);


?>
```